# Reference to "super separable/first/second countable" spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, soft-question, terminology, definition

I came across some pretty wild terminologies while reading some papers on general topology

http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CTGDC/CTGDC_2008__49_4/CTGDC_2008__49_4_267_0/CTGDC_2008__49_4_267_0.pdf

[image]

I tried to look for a standard reference for these terms but have not found any. Does anyone know a standard source for a collection of these "super" topological properties?

Please let me know if these are not a part of the "standard" curiculum in undergrad topology.

Comment: They are not part of the standard curriculum in undergraduate *or* graduate topology. I suspect that most of what is known can be found in this paper and its first two references, though I’ve a faint recollection that someone else, possibly Paul Bankston, did some work with what is here called super-separability back in the 1970s or early 1980s.

Comment: @bof: The authors are interested in what happens without $\mathsf{AC}$, and in how much choice is needed to get the ‘obvious’ results.

Comment: This question should be tagged with `axiom-of-choice`. With AC, the "super" first and second countability are simply equivalent to normal first and second countability (respectively), which *is* a part of the "standard" curriculum in undergrad topology (it certainly was a part of mine). I'm not sure about the super separability -- at a glance, it seems nontrivial even with AC, though I suspect it *might* be equivalent to hereditary density.

Comment: @tomasz _Super separablity_ is not equivalent to hereditary separability (which is what I think you meant to write). The [Moore plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane) is super separable, but not hereditarily separable. (To see that it is super separable, note that any dense subspace of the Moore plane must include a dense set of points $(x,y)$ with $y > 0$, and taking a countable dense set of these will yield a dense subset of the subspace. It is not hereditarily separable since the $x$-axis is an uncountable discrete set.)

Comment: @0x690105: Good point. Still, my point about the first and second countability stands.

Comment: An example  (with AC) of a separable space that is not super separable :  Let $D=\{0,1\}$  be discrete.Let $X=D^{\omega_1}$  with the Tychonoff product topology. Then $X$ is separable by the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery Theorem. The subspace of all $f\in X$ such that $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is countable or$ f^{-1}\{1\}$ is countable is dense in $X$ but not separable.